# java jersey 2 how to process regular html form array with post?

Tags: java, forms, rest, jersey

I have a jersey endpoint

```
@Path(value = "/testfields")
@POST
@Consumes({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
public Response acceptFields(@BeanParam MyWrapper    initialWrapper,String entity) {
  //.......

}
```

MyWrapper is:

```
class MyWrapper{
    @FormParam("param1")
    private String param1;
    @FormParam("inners")
    private List<MyInnerWrapper> inners;

    //..getters setters
}

class MyInnerWrapper{
    @FormParam("innerParam1")
    private String innerParam1;

//.... getters setters


}
```

I have request POST entity string:

```
param1=aaa&inners[0]["innerParam"]=bbb&inners[1]["innerParam"]=nnn
```

The issue is I can obtain parent`s field param1 with @BeanParam annotation, but I can't obtain inner list of custom classes, why? How to process regular html form array? I need to get my class evaluated with its inner classes in my endpoint. I tried array, list of objects, nothing works. Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you see that type of syntax for the request params, that made you think it should work? Did you see an example somewhere? I've never seen that used before in Jersey

Comment: Thank you, this is just regular POST request that my employer sends to the endpoint. he has html form and list of items there. Every item is set of input fields. He can add as many items as he needs. Then he serializes the form and sends to this endpoint. Why do you think it's strange?

Comment: Because I have never seen that syntax used before in Jersey. Normally form parameters are simple key value pairs, where the keys are simple strings. Any support for the above syntax I imagine would be framework dependent. I'm not saying that I haven't seen that syntax before, but not in Jersey. It may have even been in another language that I say support for that syntax. That's why I was asking have you ever seen that syntax actually used before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, that type of syntax is not supported in Jersey. If you want to use custom types for `@FormParam`, then you need to meet the requirements of at least one those listed in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html). One options is to just have a constructor with a String argument. For example

```
public class MyInnerWrapper {

    private final String innerParam;

    public MyInnerWrapper(String param) {
        this.innerParam = param;
    }

    public String getInnerParam() {
        return innerParam;
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is send this request

```
param1=blahparam&inners=first&inners=second&inners=third
```

Then you can have

```
@FormParam("inners")
private List<MyInnerWrapper> inners;
```

There's no need for an `[]` to specify indices. Duplicates are allowed. That's why we are allowed to have lists and arrays for the `@FormParam` types.

Now if you want to have more than one property and then try to map them like you currently are, I don't think that will work. At least not in Jersey. I would recommend maybe looking into using JSON if you need more complex types. Otherwise just stick to simple keys.

Comment: Ok thanks, but may I have 2 @BeanParam annotation arguments? One for simple fields for parent class, and another for rest of clilds? I tried, but no luck

Comment: My answer is based on your current code, and not any adjustments you've made to it. I have tested my answer and it works fine. I just removed `String entity`

Comment: Ok thanks, the issue is in MyWrapper I have 4-5 fields, and may be even more. That's why probably it won't work. Btw, JSON request works like a charm :), but I need request like I wrote above. :( Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't matter how many fields `MyWrapper` has. You should be able to have as many as you want. It's `MyInnerWrapper` that is the problem. Each inner wrapper should only present one key value pair. By `MyWrapper` can have hold as many keys are you want.

Comment: Thanks, yes, and it's not possible for me because I have request structure as I wrote above. May be use sth like preparer, which will convert request before sending to an endpoint. But is this case it's reasonable to convert it to json directly. I'm searching for java library that may parse query array like I wrote. As I understood, there's no way to do it like a charm, like it would be done with json.